# Calling an Object by an Integer

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to edit some objects texts with this:

```
' Textbox1
' Textbox2
' Textbox3

Sub Change_Text()

    Dim i As Integer


    For i = 1 To 3

        UserForm1.Textbox & i = "Hi"

    Next i

End Sub
```

I think the code explain my problem, of course it's returning an error, I don't have idea what to do...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it like that

```
For i = 1 To 3
    Controls("Textbox" & i) = "Hi"
Next i
```

Comment: Ok, It worked! But I got another problem, how to do that to change text in another userform? Like this:


Controls("UserForm1.TXT_Banco_" & VAR_Repeticoes) = "Hi"

It's returning "Could not find the specified object."

Comment: You did not ask this. I'd suggest to close this question and create another post because you need to explain more what you you really want to do.

Comment: I've to wait 80 more minutes to create another topic... I'll post the link here when I do that.

Comment: @HeitorBadotti you are trying to construct the name of the control i guess, but you don't need to refer the userform in the name of the control, but the actual path to the control, i.e.: `UserForm1.Controls("TXT_Banco_" & VAR_Repeticoes) = "Hi"` . I haven't tested, but i`m pretty sure that's the problem.

Comment: Yes!!! That's this... I found the solution right now in google... I never heard about Controls command... Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the optimal solution (least from your example) would be to loop over all the `Textbox`es

```
Private Sub loop_through_conts()
  Dim cont as Control
  For Each cont in Me.Controls
     If TypeName(cont) = "Textbox" Then
        Select Case Right(cont.Name, 1) ' in case you want only first three
        Case 1 To 3
           cont.Text = "Hi"
        End Select
     End If
  Next cont
End Sub
```

This way your code is dynamic and does not have to be re-written in case a new `Textbox` were to be added

Comment: That's a solution but not for my problem, because I don't want all textboxes with "Hi"... The Storax answer was the best but I got this problem which I commented on

Comment: Can easily be ammended to accept only first three, check my edited answer

Comment: Also it's better programming practice to refer to `Control` object via reference, rather than name. In case the name changed, or even the file was opened in different language pack, then `Controls("Textbox" & i)` will no longer work

Comment: Ok, but I got the another problem, I need to change these textboxes in another userform... I tried to change

For Each cont in Me.Controls
to
For Each cont in UserForm3.Controls

but didn't work.